# Can a tweet be added to graduate research proposal?

Tags: research-proposal, social-media

Can I add a tweet by someone famous in the field into my research proposal to show why is it important?

I am asking this because I have not seen anything like this but people do use quotes by famous people in their thesis.

If the answer is yes, then how will I be citing it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can quote any source, including Twitter. Cite it in the same way you'd cite any web source and be aware that it might disappear.

Comment: I agree with @user2768 here, but want to add that it is possible to archive tweets using archive.org, so if they are important for your research you can make sure to archive them for future reference.